# Pulling firebase document gets superfluous data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase, and when i perform a get command for a firestore document it returns a ton of data that are not fields i set myself. Is there anyway to get only the user defined data? Example below, only 6 of these were user defined fields. None of the others are even visible in the web console.

code...

```
db.collection("profiles").doc("a").get();
```

response

> I: [] ​​ length: 0 ​​ : Array [] ​ J: true ​ O: Array [ ()
> ] ​ P: Array [] ​ Sb: Object { l: "[redacted]", … } ​ W: function () ​
> Xa: null ​ Y: Object { l: false, settings: {…}, W: "[redacted]", … } ​
> Z: Object { l: false, settings: {…}, W: "[redacted]", … } ​
> _lat: "[redacted]" ​ a: Object { c: "[redacted]", … } ​ b: Object { a: "[redacted]", c: 1611707738951, … } ​ da: Object { a: "[redacted]", b:
> {…} } ​ displayName: "[redacted]" ​ email: "[redacted]" ​
> emailVerified: false ​ ga: null ​ h: null ​ i: Object { v: 0, B:
> "[redacted]", … } ​ isAnonymous: false ​ l: "[redacted]" ​ la:
> undefined ​ m: "[redacted]" ​ ma: "[redacted]" ​ metadata: Object { a:
> "[redacted]", … } ​ o: "[redacted]" ​ phoneNumber: null ​ photoURL:
> null ​ providerData: Array [ {…} ] ​ refreshToken: "[redacted]" ​
> tenantId: null ​ u: Object { src: {…}, a: {…}, b: 3 } ​ uid:
> "[redacted]" ​ va: false ​ w: Object { c: 30000, f: 960000, a: 30000,
> … } ​ wa: function wa(e)​ xa: function xa(e)​ : {…

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're printing is the entire `DocumentSnapshot`, which contains a lot more metadata in addition to the actual data of the document.

To see only the data:

```
let documentSnapshot = await db.collection("profiles").doc("a").get();
console.log(documentSnapshot.data());
```